# tcpclient - how to guarantee response is for the correct async command?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Forgive me if this is covered somewhere but my google skills have failed me and there doesn't appear to be anything that covers this specific problem. I've come to use tcpclient for the first time (TcpClient and NetworkStream with StreamReader and StreamWriter) and there's a few intricacies that i'm trying to understand.

**Background**

I'm communicating with a printer, I open up the network stream reader that loops infinitely and parses incoming data. Outward commands are sent asynchronously from user inputs on the ui. All good so far.

A lot of examples show you sending data and then waiting upon the response, fine in most circumstances. My issue is that the printer can randomly send me data that I have to respond to (out of ink / faults etc) and I send commands to it asynchronously.  I'm also paranoid that it may not always process commands in order.

I know the size of the expected responses and I can always split the commands out from the stream reliably (they always use start and end characters).  The issue is that a lot of the responses have the same size and format.

My initial thought was to create a queue of outgoing commands, when a response comes back I can check it against the first in the queue to see if it matches the expected return format and the others if it doesn't.

If it doesn't match anything in the queue, treat it as a new responses and try and figure out what it might have sent me.

**Question**

I guess simply put, are my assumptions correct? (I haven't experienced these problems yet, but I don't want to be surprised in production) and are there any commonly accepted ways of dealing with this type of scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Your thoughts are mostly right. Is there a way to reliably match up requests and responses or will there always be guessing involved?

Comment: I can match up maybe 60% straight out, the rest I may be able to narrow down (they're have different ranges on the return data - but mostly overlap so still guesswork) but others i'll just have to rely on the order they came back in :(

Comment: If the order was guaranteed that would be totally valid to rely on. I'm not sure how to answer you because you need to have a way to match responses to requests.